# HtmlAgilityPack and large HTML Documents

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I have built a little crawler and now when trying it out i found that when crawling certain sites my crawler uses 98-99% CPU.

I used `dotTrace` to see what the problem could be and it pointed me towards my `httpwebrequest` method - i optimised it a bit with the help of some previous questions here on stackoverflow.. but the problem was still there.

I then went to see what URLs that were causing the CPU load and found that it was actually sites that are extremely large in size - go figure :) 
So, now i am 99% certain it has to do with the following piece of code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument documentt = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection list;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection frameList;

documentt.LoadHtml(_html);
list = documentt.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]");
```

All that i want to do is to extract the links on the page, so for large sites.. is there anyway i can get this to not use so much CPU?

I was thinking maybe limit what i fetch? What would be my best option here?

Certainly  someone must have run into this problem before :)

Comment: Edit: Apologies for my English, please let me know if something is unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".//a[@href]" is extremely slow XPath. Tried to replace with "//a[@href]" or with code that simply walks whole document and checks all A nodes.

Why this XPath is slow:

1. "." starting with a node
2. "//" select all descendent nodes
3. "a" - pick only "a" nodes
4. "@href" with href.

Portion 1+2 ends up with "for every node select all its descendant nodes" which is very slow.

Comment: That helped a bit, but am still getting CPU spikes. Any idea what more could be done?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov
I don't think that it works that way. Isn't it that dot represent here current node which is current object - document node? As far as I understand both your xpaths should work exatly the same - lack of dot should mean root - also document node.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dropping the XPath and using the LINQ functionality?

```
var list = documentt.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Select(n => n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
```

That'll pull a list of the href attribute of all anchor tags as a List<string>.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't heavily invested in Html Agility Pack, try using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) instead. It builds an index when parsing the documents, and selectors are much faster than HTML Agility Pack. See [a comparison.](http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/06/csquery-performance-vs-fizzler.html)

CsQuery is a .NET jQuery port with a full CSS selector engine; it lets you use CSS selectors as well as the jQuery API to access and manipulate HTML. It's on nuget as CsQuery.