# Html Agility Pack LoadHtml method issue with large file size with more than 100MB

Tags: c#

I am using HtmlAglitiypack to parsing html files, **LoadHtml** method working fine for small size files. But when i am using file more than 100 MB size, LoadHtml and SelectNodes methods are stuck.Is there any file size limitation in HtmlAgilitypack?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);    
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/th");
```

Comment: This might help...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804281/htmlagilitypack-and-large-html-documents

Comment: LoadHtml method is itself throwing exception System.OutOfMemoryException